# Как разместить много яндекс карт на одной страницы без id?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Внутри большого (даже неограниченного) количества табов есть карта, инициализирую:

```
ymaps.ready(function(){

    $('.tab-item').click(function(){

        var myMap;
        initYaMap();

        myMap = new ymaps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('tracking-map__yandex-map'), {
            center: [53.35, 83.73],
            zoom: 4
        });

    });

});

function initYaMap () {

}
```

id использовать нельзя. Полагаю, что нужно вместо строки передавать найденный элемент по принципу `$('.classname')[0]`

Но ничего не выходит. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался? Есть ли решение данного вопроса, с API знаком, не нужно ссылок на него, я стремлюсь решить задачу, я не прошу кого-то погуглить вместо меня.

Comment: Так в API русским языком написано, что можно передать HTML элемент. `document.getElementsByClassName('tracking-map__yandex-map')` возвращает коллекцию, надо брать из неё какой-нибудь элемент

Comment: @AlexeyTen циклом перебирать в общем

Comment: @AlexeyTen идентифицировать этот элемент по чему?

Comment: Это же ваши элементы. Вам лучше знать как их идентифицировать

Comment: Покажите "скелет" вашего html. Как я понял  у вас что то типа `body (.tab-item + (.tab-content .tracking-map__yandex-map)`. Например есть вкладка (таб), ее заголовок имеет класс `tab-item`, при клике на него показывается контент таба (допустим имеет класс `tab-content`) и в контенте есть одна карта с классом `tracking-map__yandex-map`. Похоже я нафантазировал?

Comment: @tutankhamun спасибо, что откликнулись, выложу на codepen в ближайшее время